# Run-time error 1004: application defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I have a button in one of the sheets (sheet"Welcome")
And the button calls the form, when I put the data in the text boxes, I would like to put the data in another sheet ("OportunidadesemAberto") when I click the commandbutton2. But nothing happens, it changes the view of the "oportunidadesemaberto" sheet, but the error appears in that line.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Sheets("OportunidadesemAberto").Activate
  Range("A2").Select
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OportunidadesemAberto")
  Dim le As Long
  lr = Sheets("OportunidadesemAberto").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(x1up).Row
  With sh
    .Cells(lr + 1, "A").Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
    .Cells(lr + 1, "B").Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
    .Cells(lr + 1, "C").Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
    .Cells(lr + 1, "D").Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
    .Cells(lr + 1, "E").Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
    .Cells(lr + 1, "F").Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
    .Cells(lr + 1, "G").Value = Me.TextBox7.Value
    .Cells(lr + 1, "H").Value = Me.TextBox8.Value
    .Cells(lr + 1, "I").Value = Me.TextBox9.Value
    .Cells(lr + 1, "J").Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    .Cells(lr + 1, "K").Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value
    .Cells(lr + 1, "L").Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value
  End With
End Sub
```

I checked the trust center, and the error's still here. I tried to pass the data to other sheets. nothing works

When I debug it, then it shows this error:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

[image: When DEbug it shows this error]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [MCVE] (be sure to add the code in your question, not an image!) :)

Comment: @SamuelEverson new here! Thank your for the tip.

Comment: In your line `lr = Sheets("OportunidadesemAberto").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(x1up).Row`. 
`End(x1up)` should be `End(xlup)`. 
Notice the number `1` (one) in the first should be a lower case `l` (L) per the second. 
This however will throw a `Run time error 9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
Dim le as long
lr = Sheets("YourSheetName").range("YourRange").end(xlUp).row
```

It could be a simple spelling mistake of using **lr** instead of **le** in the above code.
Not sure though, if that will fix your problem. If not fixed, kindly provide the code snippet.

Refactored code: It is best to reference the objects explicitly

```
Dim le as long
le = Sh.range("A" & Sh.rows.count).end(xlUp).row
```

Comment: The variable name typo won't cause the `Runtime Error 1004` but a potential misspelling of sheet name etc. will. @pambiesdesign `Option Explicit` will avoid typo's in your code - if you add it to the top of your code module you will get a `Compile Error` as `lr` isn't a declared variable.

Comment: I use the refactored code `Dim le as long
le = Sh.range("A" & Sh.rows.count).end(xlUp).row` and now I can add data , but it starts to write in the first row where I have my columns names. @SamuelEverson

Comment: @PambiesDesign you need to replace "lr" with "le" throughout that sub or just change "le" with "lr" in the line **Dim le as long le = Sh.range("A" & Sh.rows.count).end(xlUp).row**

Comment: @PambiesDesign  If solved, kindly mark as answered.... :)